# Quarkus application.properties not being picked from test/resources in Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, quarkus

I am working on a project with Quarkus and have a CI pipeline running on Gitlab, for building the project from the pipeline I am using `mvn clean package -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true`, its not picking up the application.properties from the test/resources but from the main/resources.

I also tried supplying some properties with `QuarkusTestProfile` and `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` but no luck.

And the strange part is `mvn clean package` works fine on my machine with `QuarkusTestProfile` and `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`.

Have anyone faced a similar issue?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Quarkus runs the application in test profile.

Comment: What properties are you trying to supply with `QuarkusTestProfile` and `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`?

Comment: kafka.bootstrap.servers

Comment: I'm using that and it works properly. Can you add some code snippets?